# How to achieve shadows with text using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I manipulate text with shadows in CSS to achieve an effect like the “30 Free Vector Icons” text below?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

try this :

**HTML :**

```
<div style="background:#ccccc;"><h1 class="myshadow">Cool text</h1></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
    h1.myshadow{
            color: #C8C8C8;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px white, -1px -1px #444;
    }
```

CSS property you need to use is  `text-shadow`

More info : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

Answer (score 2):

Here some info about CSS3 shadows

Different methods are showed here to achieve box shadow and text shadows
http://www.webdesignshock.com/css3-drop-shadow

The following have text shadow examples

http://line25.com/articles/using-css-text-shadow-to-create-cool-text-effects

And to visually match your example, this demo is using the same colors and effets

http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/text-shadow/demo/index.html

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way

Answer (score 2):

There is the [`text-shadow`](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/text-shadow) property, which is reasonably well-supported outside of Internet Explorer. [IE’s `Glow` filter](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/filter%3Aprogid%3ADXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow%28%29) provides a kind of similar effect.

Safari and Chrome also have [`-webkit-text-stroke`](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke), but that’s not supported anywhere else.